# Texture Paint dot

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to use the Texture Painting Tool, but I get some ugly results :3. When I'm using a Noise Texture, I get a small dot in the middle.

[image]

I'm painting on a plane, which I divided 5 times in x and y, then UV-unwrapped it, scaled it by 5, add a Material, add a Texture, new Texture with 2048 x 2048 in UV-View.

Answer (score 1):

Okay... and I changed the curve to vector handle which is a bad idea, it should be a clean curve, problem solved, I think it should stay for people <3.